# Making a file list in python

Tags: python, file-listing

I don't know where's the problem. Can you help me?

main.py

```
import os
from functions import *


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = os.getenv('path')
    print(readFiles(path))
```

functions.py

```
import os

def readFiles(patha):
    res = []

    # Iterate directory
    currentpath = os.listdir(patha)
    
    for path in currentpath:
        # check if current path is a file
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(patha, path)):
            res.append(path)
        else:
            pathf = patha + path + '/'
            res.append(readFiles(pathf))


    return res
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDTsq.png)

I wanted to make a file list in python and this error appeared. No idea what went wrong.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your error. Instead, copy paste the error to your post

Comment: In your screenshot, it says "patha", a typo I believe.

Comment: Your "PATH" environment variable is composed of several directories separated by `;`. `os.listdir` expects one directory to be passed, and is thus raising an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `os.getenv('path')` variable to make sure it is as expected. Also, I updated your code to make it work smoothly.

```
from pathlib import Path


def readFiles(patha):
    res = []
    print(patha)

    # Iterate directory
    currentpath = os.listdir(patha)

    for path in currentpath:
        # check if current path is a file
        try:
            f = os.path.join(patha, path)
            if os.path.isfile(f):
                res.append(f)
            elif os.path.isdir(f):
                res.extend(readFiles(f))
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print("warning,", e)

    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = Path.cwd()
    print(readFiles(path))
```

I suggest you to take a look at this question as well:
[How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory?rq=1)